# Getting element length with php DOM

Tags: php

I'm stuck with this.
I try to use php dom to parse some html code.
How can I get to know how many children current element has witch I iterate through in for loop?

```
<?php
$str='
<table id="tableId">
<tr>
    <td>row1 cell1</td>
    <td>row1 cell2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row2 cell1</td>
    <td>row2 cell2</td>
</tr>
</table>
';

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str);   // loading page contents
$table = $DOM->getElementById('tableId');   // getting the table that I need
$DOM->loadHTML($table);     

$tr = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');     // getting rows

echo $tr->item(0)->nodeValue;   // outputs row1 cell1 row1 cell2 - exactly as I expect with both rows
echo "<br>";
echo $tr->item(1)->nodeValue;   // outputs row2 cell1 row2 cell2

// now I need to iterate through each row to build an array with cells that it has
for ($i = 0; $i < $tr->length; $i++)
{
echo $tr->item($i)->length;     // outputs no value. But how can I get it?
echo $i."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477790/php-dom-not-retrieving-element. Same issues.

Comment: do you need the DOM to do that? otherwise i could show you [another](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) way..

Comment: DOMDocument::loadHTML takes an html string, on your second call to it(which seems pointless) you pass a DOMElement.

Comment: Im not completely familiar with PHP DOM, but since it is PHP and since it appears your working with Objects/Arrays couldn't you apply something like `echo count($tr)`. Again not one hundred percent on that but just a thought.

Comment: @Greg: other issue. That one is about fragments & getElementById not working. That part works here. Although there is probably a duplicate out there, for instance [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191923/how-do-i-iterate-through-dom-elements-in-php).

Answer (score 2):

This will give you all [childnodes](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes):

```
$tr->item($i)->childNodes->length;
```

... but: it will contain `DOMText` nodes with whitespace etc (so the count is 4). If you don't necessarily need the length, just want to iterate over all the nodes, you can do this:

```
foreach($tr->item($i)->childNodes as $node){
    if($node instanceof DOMElement){
        var_dump($node->ownerDocument->saveXML($node));
    }
}
```

If you need only a length of elements, you can do this:

```
$x = new DOMXPath($DOM);
var_dump($x->evaluate('count(*)',$tr->item($i)));
```

And you can do this:

```
foreach($x->query('*',$tr->item($i)) as $child){
    var_dump($child->nodeValue);
}
```

foreach-ing through the `->childNodes` has my preference for simple 'array-building'. Keep in mind you van just `foreach` through `DOMNodeList`'s as if they were arrays, saves a lot of hassle.

Building a simple array from a table:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str);   // loading page contents
$table = $DOM->getElementById('tableId'); 
$result = array();
foreach($table->childNodes as $row){
   if(strtolower($row->tagName) != 'tr') continue;
   $rowdata = array();
   foreach($row->childNodes as $cell){
       if(strtolower($cell->tagName) != 'td') continue;
       $rowdata[] = $cell->textContent;
   }
   $result[] = $rowdata;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: In your second code, you dump/saveXML the node if instanceof DOMElement. What would the others have? Will I be missing something by omitting them?

Comment: @sergio: instances of `DOMNode` which aren't `DOMElements` includes amount others raw text not in an element (so not a subnode) for instance random whitespace (all those enters and tabs usually found in HTML to format it visually). For a complete list of what is a `Node`, but not an `Element`, look at the [DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1590626202)