# DOMDocument return empty data

Tags: php, html, curl, domdocument

I am try to learn data scrapping from other website so I started by trying creating a small HTML file.

**domhtml.php :**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="mango">
            This is the mango div. It has some text and a form too.
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" value="Yahoo" />
                <input type="text" name="last_name" value="Bingo" />
            </form>

            <table class="inner">
                <tr><td>Happy</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <table id="data" class="outer">
            <tr><td>Happy1</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Happy2</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Happy3</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Happy4</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Happy5</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**extract.php :**

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://192.168.0.198/projects/domhtml.php");

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$cl = curl_exec($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($cl);
$dom->validate();
$title = $dom->getElementById("mango");

//var_dump($title);exit;

//$title = $dom->saveXML($title);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($title);


?>
```

But it returns output :

```
DOMElement Object
(
)
```

why it is empty ? What is to be done other then this ? I also tried [PHP Dom not retrieving element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477790/php-dom-not-retrieving-element) solution but it return the same.

**Edit :**

Ok as you all guys told me I have done this :

```
$ch = curl_init("http://192.168.0.198/shopclues/domhtml.php");

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$cl = curl_exec($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($cl);
$dom->validate();
$title = $dom->getElementById("data");

//var_dump($title);exit;

$title = $dom->saveXML($title);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($title);
```

So now it is printing :

```
Happy1  Sky
Happy2  Sky
Happy3  Sky
Happy4  Sky
Happy5  Sky
```

I want to know the how many tr tag is there so that I can store the value of each tr in some variable. I mean how can I loop to store the value into variable ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `$cl` contain the HTML after the `curl_exec()` ?

Comment: Does the `echo $dom->saveXML($title);` or  `echo $dom->saveHTML($title);` show something to you? `DOMElement` is just a wrapper to a native library so it is nothing uncommon that it looks empty on a `print_r`

Comment: @RichardBernards yes it shows the page

Comment: I recommend you do `display_errors` on and `error_reporting` at max level when developing so you can see the warnings from your validate() call (I would only use it with XHTML).  I've run your code as is (minus the validate call) and everything works as expected for me.

Comment: Your edit is a new question, so you should open a new one for this.

Answer (score 0):

The default "__toString()" functions in the DOM classes have been steadily improving:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/hw9UKg

Run the code in the snippet above using different versions of PHP, you'll see the difference between 5.3.3 and 5.4.33.

For the second part of your question, there are many ways to do what you want.  I will show you one:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// I used a different URL
$dom->loadHtmlFile("http://192.168.0.198/shopclues/domhtml.php");
$list = $dom->getElementById("data")->childNodes;

print_r($list->length); // outputs 5 for me.
```

`$list` is a `DOMNodeList` which implements `Traversable` so you can loop over it to get the values.  For more information, check:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php

For more complex queries, you may want to look into `DOMXPath`:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

It would also be beneficial to read all the functions available to you with `DomDocument` and `DomNode`:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Comment: thank for your valuable answer. I tried this and it show value 5. If i try to `print_r($list);` then it show `DOMNodeList Object ( )`. How can I know what element I have to store inside my loop?

Comment: Also you have written $list->length, what all other attributes ? I mean to say `$list->....` ? I don't know why your answer is downvoted. Downvoter please explain the reason

Comment: I have provided a link to `DOMNodeList`, you can see all the other attributes/methods on that page.

Comment: but can you please explain me why I am getting empty while doing print_r ?

Comment: The __toString() methods in the DOM classes are becoming better.  What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: The __toString() functions in that version were like that.  Run the code snippet here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hw9UKg using different versions of PHP, you'll see at 5.4.33 the __toString() function started showing more information.